# Why does iOS 4.2 iPad update break this website layout?

Tags: css, ipad, ios, layout, ios-4.2

I've been asked to fix a layout issue for http://www.ireland.com, which occurs on an iPad running iOS 4.2 only. The body content floats right and the header left, rather than all centred as they are on all other platforms and vendors.

Anyone aware of such issues or know how I might fix this?

I've only access to the iOS simulator on my macbook and can't get firebuglite working because it blocks copying bookmarklets. I wish I had some decent debug tools!

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: Maybe the ipad browser is making different assumptions about the errors on the site.  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ireland.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 I would advise fixing a majority of the errors and then going from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReadWriteWeb says that iOS 4.2 updates the browser with many new features. My only guess is that a new feature is reacting strangely with your CSS. Are you using a reset stylesheet on your website?

http://www.readwriteweb.com/mobile/2010/11/what-web-developers-should-kno.php